# Trying to automate some data scraping but need insight on how to combine data between scrape and export

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver 3")

player_ids = ['114']
rd_id = 1

# iterating through player_ids

for i in player_ids:
    team_id = i
    base_url = "https://bet365.apps.imgarena.com/golf/3.18.0/full/?eventId=183&language=en&options=eyJ2aWRlb1BsYXliYWNrRW5hYmxlZCI6ZmFsc2V9#/leaderboard/team/"
    mid_url = "?roundNo="
    end_url = "&holeNo=1"
    team_url = base_url + str(team_id) + mid_url + str(rd_id) + end_url

    driver.get(team_url)


    shotsbtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span[1]')))
    shotsbtn.click()

    results = []

#   iterating through each hole 1-18

    for i in range(1, 3):
        hole_id = i
        base_xpath = '//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div['
        end_xpath = ']/span[1]'
        full_xpath = base_xpath + str(hole_id) + end_xpath

        sleep(randint(2,5))

        holebtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,full_xpath)))
        holebtn.click()

        sleep(randint(2,5))

        content = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

#   pulling required shot data from each hole

        for a in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'text__42f569fe no-name__42f569fe'}):
            name = a.find
            results.append(name)


#   exporting information by player to.csv

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Player': results})
    df.to_csv('player_' + str(team_id) + '.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

What I'm looking to do is extract 'player name' and/or 'team_id' along with each 'hole_id' so that **every shot is uniquely identified**.

At the moment I get this opened as a .csv:

At the moment I get something looking like this:

```
Shot 4: </span <span in the hole for Par</span</div
Shot 3: </span <span stroke 3, 41 yds to Green, 9 ft 6 in. left to pin</span</div
Shot 2: </span <span stroke 2, 135 yds to Rough, 43 yds left to pin</span</div
Shot 1: </span <span stroke 1, 281 yds to Rough, 177 yds left to pin</span</div
```

And ideally I'm hoping to get it to look something more like this:

```
Hole 1, 114, 'Hatton, Tyrrell', Shot 4: </span <span in the hole for Par</span</div
Hole 1, 114, 'Hatton, Tyrrell', Shot 3: </span <span stroke 3, 41 yds to Green, 9 ft 6 in. left to pin</span</div
Hole 1, 114, 'Hatton, Tyrrell', Shot 2: </span <span stroke 2, 135 yds to Rough, 43 yds left to pin</span</div
Hole 1, 114, 'Hatton, Tyrrell', Shot 1: </span <span stroke 1, 281 yds to Rough, 177 yds left to pin</span</div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of hard-work, I have come up with the final code. Here it is:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

player_ids = ['114','115']
rd_id = 1

dictionary = {'Hole Number': [],
              'Id': [],
              'Player name': [],
              'Shot number': [],
              'Shot details': []}

# iterating through player_ids

name_list = []
hole_num_list = []
id_list = []
shot_data_final = []
shot_num_list = []

for i in player_ids:
    team_id = i
    base_url = "https://bet365.apps.imgarena.com/golf/3.18.0/full/?eventId=183&language=en&options=eyJ2aWRlb1BsYXliYWNrRW5hYmxlZCI6ZmFsc2V9#/leaderboard/team/"
    mid_url = "?roundNo="
    end_url = "&holeNo=1"
    team_url = base_url + str(team_id) + mid_url + str(rd_id) + end_url

    driver.get(team_url)


    shotsbtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span[1]')))
    shotsbtn.click()

    results = []

#   iterating through each hole 1-18

    for i in range(1, 3):

        hole_id = i
        base_xpath = '//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div['
        end_xpath = ']/span[1]'
        full_xpath = base_xpath + str(hole_id) + end_xpath

        sleep(randint(2,5))

        holebtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,full_xpath)))
        holebtn.click()

        sleep(randint(2,5))

        content = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

        name = soup.find('div',class_ = "player-name__691c96bc").text

        hole_num = int(soup.find('span',class_ = "inner__-3c5fde4a active__-3c5fde4a").text)

        shot_data = soup.find('ul',class_ = "list__3ed248d4").find_all('li')

        for shot in shot_data:
            shott = shot.text.split(':')
            shot_num = shott[0]
            shot_num_list.append(shot_num)
            shot_data_final.append(shott[-1].strip())


        for x in range(len(shot_data_final) - len(id_list)):
            name_list.append(name)
            hole_num_list.append(hole_num)
            id_list.append(team_id)
        
        hole_num_list.append('')
        id_list.append('')
        name_list.append('')
        shot_num_list.append('')
        shot_data_final.append('')

driver.close()
dictionary['Hole Number'] = hole_num_list
dictionary['Id'] = id_list
dictionary['Player name'] = name_list
dictionary['Shot number'] = shot_num_list
dictionary['Shot details'] = shot_data_final

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

df.to_csv('Shots.csv',index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

The code is pretty-much self-explanatory, so I don't think that there is much to explain. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx Sushil, .csv file now looks spot on. Just cycling through it now to iron out the issue of overwriting the hole data after each loop. I'm sure it's an indentation issue where the lists are resetting to empty thereby only getting shot data for 1 hole instead of all 18?

Comment: I have changed it. Check it out.

Comment: @dataguy I spotted few errors in my code, so I have updated it. Check out my latest edit. I have provided the full code and it works perfectly fine. Just copy paste it into your editor and tell me the result.

Comment: Thx, I'd been tinkering with your original solution code as it was almost there but not quite. Now it's perfect.